# Mount Point comparison

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell function that pulls the free space on a mounted volume. Ideally I would like to take the results and do a If comparison on the value.

If the results equal true I would write that to a text file. This will allow me to use REGEX through a monitoring tool to create a trouble ticket.

I am having issues doing any comparisons on the results. Here is a snip of the code.

```bsh
$FreePerc = @{name="Free(%)";expression={[Math]::Round(((($_.FreeSpace / 1073741824)/($_.Capacity / 1073741824)) * 100),0)}}

function Get-Mountpoints {
  $volumes = Get-WmiObject -Computer localhost Win32_Volume |
             Where-Object {$_.DriveLetter -eq $null}
  $volumes | Select $FreePerc | Write-Output
}
```

The `Get-Mountpoints` function returns the correct results but I have been unable to run any comparison on it.

Comment: How did you compare the value? Against which reference value? What were desired and actual result of the comparison?

Comment: You need to show the comparison you tried.  I imagine you're not correctly using the property name you defined.  `$o = Get-Mountpoints; $o.'Free(%)' -gt 1` works fine, but I had to quote the property name.  `Free(%)` isn't a great property name anyway.  Consider something like `FreePercentage`.

Comment: Thanks Matthew Wetmore that worked perfect. That is exactly what I needed to occur. The way I was doing the comparison was incorrect. I appreciate the help.